# What is the cause of [alert] HTTP: unable to determine chunk size

Tags: benchmarking, load-testing, siege

I'm getting this error with siege, I'm not too sure what the cause of it is:
`[alert] HTTP: unable to determine chunk size` - this seems to occur randomly, but when it does happen, it occurs multiple times in a row.

Would it impact the results of my bench marking at all?

Answer (score 0):

as i have the same error and siege is a load testing tool:

i assume you got blocked by the server due to excessive requests.
and it will impact your results.